# Cannot access variable before initialisation error in Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently working on a Twitter clone, using Vue 3. The source code for the same can be found [here](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/Almost-Twitter).

The code for the `HomeView.vue` is as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Tweet 
      v-for="tweet in tweets" 
      :key="tweet._id" 
      :tweet="tweet" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Tweet from '../components/Tweet';
import tweets from '../tweets';

export default {
  setup () {
    const tweets = ref(tweets);

    return {
      tweets,
      Tweet
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But upon executing the same I get the following error in the developer's console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'tweets' before initialization
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Composition API expert but I guess that looking at [the lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram), you can't use tweets straight like that because they are not directly available. They are populated afterwards.

While your template is sync, hence it is erroring because it cannot access something when it's (initially) undefined.

Making a `<div class="home" v-if="tweets">` may be a solution, otherwise maybe a combo with `watch` and [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html), not sure.

PS: also you have 2 `tweets` variables here, this may cause some bugs be careful.