# Access to nested object property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access to a nested object property.

```
<th  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" v-for="schedule in employee.daily_schedules">{{schedule.start}}-{{schedule.end}}-{{schedule.employee_function.name}}</th>
```

When I try to get the schedule.employee_function.name I get an error

> (TypeError: u.employee_function is null)

but if I render schedule.employee_function I have the whole object:

[image]

This is the object that I get from the api:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Comment: Note that logging an object to the console gives you a *live view* of the object, not a snapshot of its state at the time it's logged. If something else mutates it after the console.log (like the API call succeeding) that will be reflected in the logged object but you could still have the error.

Comment: The error is just this TypeError: u.employee_function is null.

Comment: nothing mutate the api data. In fact if I don't use the attribute name i render the json object as you can see in the capture.

Comment: Can you please add how you load the data in the application ? Is it a field in the database or is it added in the code ?

Comment: Calling a method from  mounted(). Finally I added a ? as @Remicaster suggested and it works schedule.employee_function?.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a possibility of a data in the `Employees` array containing an null value in the `employee_function` (for example the `employee_function` object contained a null value instead of an object), it may cause the type error in which you are trying to read an null object.

The easiest way to solve this is by adding a `?` in front of the attribute you are referencing the object from. For example `employee_function?.name`. This means that if the `employee_function` is null, it will not read any attributes that is connected to the code.

Answer (score 0):

`schedule.employee_function.name` should be enough, regarding your `v-for` and the structure of your data.

Comment: I think should be enough too, but I get the error. The funny thing here is that if I dont use the attribute i render the json object with the attribute that I want to use inside.

Comment: try adding a `?` on it. `schedule.employee_function?.name`

Comment: @Remicaster adding ? works!

Comment: @MiquelÀngel because your template probably have some async things happening and the part on the left of `.name` can be undefined in some cases. Making a conditional with a `v-if` may be a solution. The [optional chaining](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining) can also work but it's more of an inline fix.

Comment: It's hard to understand for me because the data is loaded in mounted() and is used as is in the template without any other data treatment inside the component.

Comment: @Remicaster if you want to add your solution I will check as accepted

Comment: @MiquelÀngel the data still needs to come in, your template is sync so if you don't have it straight away it will error. If you have it in mounted, it may comes a few ms later on, but still not available straight away. The proper fix is still to use a `v-if` and not an optional chaining. The latter is more of a bandaid, you will not wrap a huge block of code with it.

Comment: Your situation is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74059535/8816585 You can use your network tools to see where this is coming from.

Comment: Yes, same situation. I will try to add an if as you say. Thanks @kissu